# Do I must implement BaseObservable for Two-way data binding in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I know I can implement One-way data binding either Observable fields or LiveData.

1:  The [sample code](https://github.com/android/databinding-samples/tree/master/TwoWaySample) implement Two-way data binding with Observable fields, can I implement Two-way data binding with LiveData? Is there a sample code written with Kotlin?

2:   I have read the [artical](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way), it seems that I must implement `BaseObservable` for Two-way data binding with Observable fields. Do I must implement `BaseObservable` for Two-way data binding if I can use LiveData to implement Two-way data binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question's answer is **Yes**. You can use `LiveData` in two-day data binding. I also used `LiveData` in two-way data binding. This [article](https://blog.usejournal.com/data-binding-working-with-live-data-1f86aa879b21) helped me much.

The second question's answer is LiveData by itself is a lifecycle-aware Observable. So you don't need to implement `BaseObservable`.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a  sample code to I implement Two-way data binding with LiveData?

Comment: You can try this repo https://github.com/BalakrishnanPT/DataBindingAndroid. If you find any trouble with it comment me back.

Comment: Thanks! I test your project, it seems that project doesn't work well.

Comment: Actually it's not my project. I just sent it to show you how to use live data in two-way data binding without any additional coding. Actually in using data binding with live-data reduce task than with BaseObservable. When you use data binding with live data, you don't need any extra implementation which you do for BaseObservable. it just handles all observation by itself. You need to just add "=" sign in XML , example - "@={entity.name}" .